# Error Fetching http headers laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo una consulta a un WS que devuelve `Error Fetching http headers` el resto de consultas funcionan correctamente, el proyecto está en Laravel, he encontrado varias soluciones que hablan de aplicar `ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 600);` para solucionarlo, mi problema es que no tengo ni idea de donde aplicar ese cambio ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Hola, recuerda agregar lo que investigaste o trataste, revisa [ask] sobre las preguntas que requieren opiniones, saludos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`ini_set` En el caso de laravel deberías ponerlo en el `AppServiceProvider` en `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`, en el método `boot`.

```
public function boot()
{
    init_set("MY_VAR", "MY_VALUE");
}
```

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/283541)

Comment: pregunta por dónde poner le `init_set` en Laravel... no veo que no responda la pregunta "mi problema es que no tengo ni idea de donde aplicar ese cambio ¿alguna idea?"

Comment: No entiendo la polémica, la respuesta de @S.Wasta era justo lo que necesitaba y creo que la pregunta era adecuada y acertada.